# How to get bytes data from a binary file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have to get some bytes as data from a file. But the number of bytes to be read would be different based on some bytes. Here is an example. 
Data is in the format of 128 bytes. First 64 bytes are similar. so no problem. But next 64 bytes are variable.

```
Let us say 65th byte is "a", then 
 66 + 67 bytes = var x
68+69+70+71 bytes = var y

In case 65th byte is "b" , then 
66th byte : var z
67th byte: var k
68+69 =var o
70+71+72+73 = var m
```

```
dtype = [('var1',np.uint32),('var2',np.uint16).......]
with open(filename,'rb') as fh:
    data = np.fromfile(fh,dtype)
```

Is it possible to fetch such kind of data using numpy and dtype. Or do I need to run a for loop? Loop will be expensive as this is a huge file. Any thoughts what could be the solution?

Comment: why are you using numpy for this rather than just `read`ing the file directly?  numpy is relatively expensive for small arrays like this, have you looked at `mmap`ing the file and then using `struct` to pull out the parts you need?

Comment: From 128 bytes I plan to make around 50-60 columns and there are supposed to be around 3 million rows. I am already using mmap, but thought numpy will be faster.  Do you think my assumption regarding numpy is wrong for this case?

Comment: `numpy` is fast if you can make use of whole-array operations.  For a start you could define a `dtype` that handles all 128 bytes - such as the first 64 with defined values, the rest as a `('rest', 'uint8', 64)` field (or something like that).  And see how fast that loads.  Then compare that with something using `struct` that unpacks 128 bytes blocks iteratively.

Comment: I have tried to load 128 bytes and numpy is way faster. So now I need to figure out a way to create dtype so that I can load all data in one go. Any suggestions?